# Visual C# CLR Project Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a clr project R with a User defined type called RN in it, RN looks like

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedType(Format.UserDefined)]  
public struct RN: INullable, IBinarySerialize
{
    public SqlInt64 Id { get; set; }
    public SqlGeometry G { get; set; }
    public SqlInt64? CL { get; set; }
    public SqlDouble? TT { get; set; }

    public bool HP { get { return !Object.ReferenceEquals(this.CL, null); } }

    public RN ToClass(DataRow node); 

    public RN TN(DataRow node);
    public void P(SqlCommand command);

    public IEnumerable<RN> N;

    public override bool Equals(object obj);
    public bool Equals(RN other);
    public static bool operator ==(RN rn1, RN rn2);
    public static bool operator !=(RN rn1, RN rn2);
    public override int GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString();

    public bool IsNull;

    public static RN Null;

    public static RN FromId(SqlInt64 id);

    private bool m_Null;

    public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(this.IsNull);
        if (!this.IsNull)
        {
            w.Write(this.Id.Value);
            w.Write(this.G.STAsText().Value);
            bool CLNull = this.CL.HasValue;
            w.Write(CLNull);
            if (!CLNull)
                w.Write(this.CL.GetValueOrDefault(SqlInt64.MinValue).Value);
            bool TTNull = this.TT.HasValue;
            w.Write(TTNull);
            if (!TTNull)
                w.Write(this.TT.GetValueOrDefault(SqlInt64.MinValue).Value);
        }
    }
    public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader r)
    {
        this.m_Null = r.ReadBoolean();
        if (!this.IsNull)
        {
            this.Id = r.ReadInt64();
            this.G = SqlGeometry.Parse(r.ReadString());
            bool CLNull = r.ReadBoolean();
            if (CLNull)
                this.CL = null;
            else
                this.CL = r.ReadInt64();
            bool TTNull = r.ReadBoolean();
            if (TTNull)
                this.TT = null;
            else
                this.TT = r.ReadInt64();
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to deploy the project just as a test i get the message

> Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider: Msg 6244, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 The size (0) for
>   "R.RN" is not in the
>   valid range. Size must be -1 or a
>   number between 1 and 8000.

I have no idea what this means, for anyone wondering why i have added the Format.UserDefined and implemented IBinarySerialise if the type is Format.Native i get the error

> Deploy error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider: Msg 6223, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 Type
>   "R.RN" is marked for
>   native serialization, but field
>   "k__BackingField" of type
>   "R.RN" is of type
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry",
>   which is not marked with
>   "LayoutKind.Sequential". Native
>   serialization requires the type to be
>   marked with "LayoutKind.Sequential".

It would be appreciated if someone could explain what these errors mean and how they can be resolved

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct has the `SqlUseDefinedType` attribute with `Format.UserDefined`. In that case, MaxByteSize must also be specified.

See [MSDN docs entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.format.aspx).